# Asp.net eval substring problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

.gif"/>

not work code. How to make ?

```
error: StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there's no "." in your string, then IndexOf() returns a negative number.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/7cct0x33.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This bit:

```
IndexOf(".")
```

whill be returning -1 because the `.` is not found in the string you supplied.